# What's the latest/greatest way to get Postman to query a website with authentication cookies?

Tags: api, google-chrome, postman, endpoint

For many months I was successfully using the Postman Chrome app, combined withe Postman Interceptor.  This no longer seems to work and the Postman peeps seem to be encouraging people to upgrade to their OSX version.

I use Postman to query API Endpoints on my local computer, as well as API Endpoints on different remote instances of my company's software.  Each time I do so there appear to be 4 different cookies that need to be in place to access these endpoints.

Today, I was able to call the API Endpoints by manually copying the contents of the 4 cookies from Chrome Advanced Settings into Postman, creating the cookies on-the-fly.  While this is doable, it's a major hassle.

Is there an article or video somewhere, that is relevant for the reality of November 2018 which provides the latest/greatest way to do one's work with Postman?

Comment: Have you made the request and then manually copied the cookies from the response?

Comment: As I stated, I manually recreated the cookies.  How does one copy cookies from Chrome to Postman?